# Kivy slows when importing class from another file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a GUI in python. For that I'm using the kivy library. 
The frontend is still simple and it works fine without the backend. But when I try to import a class that I need as backend slows down the program initialization. Moreover it doesn't let me enter text in the text input or click the button for transition.

This is my main:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
import os
# from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI

from connected import Connected

class Login(Screen):
    def do_login(self, loginText, passwordText):
        app = App.get_running_app()

        app.username = loginText
        app.password = passwordText

        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
        self.manager.current = 'connected'

        app.config.read(app.get_application_config())
        app.config.write()

class LoginApp(App):
    username = StringProperty(None)
    password = StringProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        manager = ScreenManager()

        manager.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
        manager.add_widget(Connected(name='connected'))

        return manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

it works fine like that. But when I uncomment the line `from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI` it just make the program unusable. Even thought it is not being use

The ivy log slows down after

```
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into InstagramAPI code I found out that the library that was making the slow down and GUI errors was

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
```

and as I'm not using the function that uses this library I comment it

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the import is correct? how about other libraries?

I assume you are using a `python-instagram` library, If so, then the import should look like `from instagram.client import InstagramAPI`, rather than `from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI`

Comment: yeah I'm sure that's the name of the file. Searching in InstagramAPI I found the package that makes the slow down and problems is:from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip